# Why can "rust cookie::CookieJar" get a value through str type

Tags: cookies, rust

I know that the underlying data structure is a `HashSet`, but why can the `get` method use the `&str` type instead of the cookie structure?

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
cookie = "0.14"
```

**src/main.rs**

```rust
use cookie::{Cookie, CookieJar};

fn main() {
    let mut jar = CookieJar::new();

    jar.add(Cookie::new("a", "one"));
    jar.add(Cookie::new("b", "two"));

    assert_eq!(jar.get("a").map(|c| c.value()), Some("one"));
    assert_eq!(jar.get("b").map(|c| c.value()), Some("two"));

    jar.remove(Cookie::named("b"));

    assert!(jar.get("b").is_none());
}
```

Comment: It's in the signature of [`CookieJar::get`](https://docs.rs/cookie/0.14.2/cookie/struct.CookieJar.html#method.get).  What do you expect?

Comment: After reading the source code, I can't understand why get method can use str to get the value of HashMap

Comment: @hewc `HashSet::get` returns the value which, when borrowed, is equal to and hashes the same as the parameter. [DeltaCookie](https://docs.rs/cookie/0.14.2/src/cookie/delta.rs.html#53-71) is a wrapper for `Cookie` whose entire purpose is to hash and compar based on the cookie name alone, which allows retrieving cookies from the set by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of `cookie-rs` [implemented](https://docs.rs/cookie/0.14.2/src/cookie/delta.rs.html#61-71) the [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) and [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait for the values of the [`HashSet`](https://docs.rs/cookie/0.14.2/src/cookie/jar.rs.html#83-87).

Here's an example mimicking the same behavior:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct Cookie<'a> {
  name: &'a str,
  id: u64,
}

impl Hash for Cookie<'_> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.name.hash(state);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Cookie<'_> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Cookie) -> bool {
        self.name == other.name
    }
}

impl Borrow<str> for Cookie<'_> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        self.name
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cookies: HashSet<Cookie> = HashSet::new();
    
    cookies.insert(Cookie {
        name: "example",
        id: 42,
    });
    
    println!("{:?}", cookies.get("example"));
}
```

That would give us:

```sh
Some(Cookie { name: "example", id: 42 })
```